# How to detect artifacts in video?

Tags: opencv, video, video-processing

I'm using OpenCV to handle videos in mp4 format. The image below is a random frame extracted from a video, and you can see the obvious distortion on the sweater.

[image: artifacts]

How can we detect such [artifacts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compression_artifact)? Or can we avoid such artifacts by extracting nearby keyframes and how?

Comment: I don't use OpenCV but as a graphics guy I can tell you, that looks more like **[video interlacing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlaced_video)**. You need to find a "de-interlace" option in that tool. It's not solved by extracting near-by keyframes and it's not a compression "artifact"

Comment: [What is Deinterlacing? Facts, solutions, examples.](http://100fps.com/)

Comment: @VC.One Do you know any tools for deinterlacing video in mp4 format? I only found solutions for avi.

Comment: Great article link. I haven't dealt with deinterlacing for ages. I don't even have a test clip to advise you on (before & after etc). Anyways you can try **[MediaCoder](http://www.mediacoderhq.com/)**. On that program the left-hand side has a box with tabs like "preview", "tasking", "video" etc. Go to the "picture" tab and click it then on right-hand side you'll see picture options including "deinterlace" (try the various options) on a short clip and export an MP4 "container" (with H.264 "video") to preview what's good.

Comment: I found ffmpeg provides serveral deinterlacing filters, e.g. [yadif](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#yadif-1) filter. Simple usage: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf yadif output.mp4`

Comment: Is the **Yadif** result a good output? If so glad you got a solution and also you should post your comment as answer so it shows others there's a possible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @VC.One suggested, these distortions are due to video interlacing. Here is a good article about interlacing/deinterlacing: [What is Deinterlacing? Facts, solutions, examples.](http://100fps.com/)

There are several tools to handle deinterlacing:

1. [Windows] The one suggested in 100fps.com: [Virtualdub](http://www.virtualdub.org/) + [DivX](http://www.divxmovies.com/codec/) codec + [AviSynth](http://www.avisynth.org/)
2. [Windows] [MediaCoder](http://www.mediacoderhq.com/) suggested by @VC.One.
3. [Windows/Linux] FFmpeg provides serveral deinterlacing filters, e.g. [yadif](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#yadif-1), [kerndeint](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#kerndeint) etc. Here is an example: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf yadif output.mp4`